# React: How can I dynamically change the entire background dynamically for light and dark mode? Redux holds my darkMode state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state, darkmode

How can I dynamically change the entire background dynamically for `light` and `dark` mode? Redux holds my `darkMode` state.

For instance, I want the background to be black when on `darkMode` and white when I'm not on darkMode. How can I dynamically adjust? With an HOC?

**Redux (useSelector):**

```js
const darkMode = useSelector((state: ReduxState) => state.accountPreferencesReducer.darkMode);
```

**Here's the issue I'm running into when I scroll all the way down (White background):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Typically with light and dark mode people generally use a context provider (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to pass in a global stylised component. A pretty example of how to do this can be seen here: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/04/dark-mode-react-apps-styled-components/

BUT

You can do a hacky way (Not suggested) of stylising your components with darkMode by reading your dark mode state from redux inside every single component that you want to be affected. Then you need to create 2 styles for each of these components and do something like:

```js
const lightStyle = { backgroundColor: "white" };
const darkStyle = { backgroundColor: "black" };
const themeStyle = state.darkMode ? darkStyle : lightStyle;
.
.
<div style = {themeStyle}>
   <JSX-components/>
</div>
```

This is a lot of work, and I suggest you use something similar to a stylised library of components that is easier to use.

Comment: The reason why I hold the state in redux is because I use redux persist to persist the darkMode state. With context, the state would go away when I refresh the page.